# How to get a Scala Map[String, Seq[String]] to a MapType in GraphQL Sangria

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

I am trying to get a Scala `Map[String, Seq[String]]` to a `MapType` in GraphQL Sangria. I think the way could be using:

```
ScalarType[Map[String, Seq[String]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, at the moment a generic `Map` is not supported by the GraphQL spec. There are several alternatives available though. I would suggest you to check out this on-going discussion:

https://github.com/facebook/graphql/issues/101

Also, it is possible to implement a [raw JSON scalar type](https://gist.github.com/OlegIlyenko/5b96f4b54f656aac226d3c4bc33fd2a6), but in general I would discourage you from using it.